# Retrieving all namespace Types

Tags: c#, reflection, namespaces

I have a project which is referencing a namespace called "EquipmentDrivers"
the namespace contains classes which run Voltmeter/Sourcemeter/NetworkAnalyzer machines in a lab. (Ie: Agilent66XX, Keithley2400)

I would like to iterate through a list of types in the namespace to find the one corresponding to a string that containes the exact name of the class. (ie: string equipmentName = "Keithley2400" and the driver is public class Keithley2400)

How do I do this? Following is my first attempt:

```
Type[] NamespaceTypes;
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.Load("EquipmentDrivers");
NamespaceTypes = myAssembly.ManifestModule.GetTypes();

for (int i = 0; i < NamespaceTypes.Length; i++)
{
 if (NamespaceTypes[i].ToString() == equiptmentName)
 {
      return new NamespaceTypes[i](primaryGPIBAddress, true);
 }
}
```

Alright, So now I have this

```
public SourceMeter ReturnSourceMeter(string equiptmentName, int primaryGPIBAddress)
{    
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("EquipmentDrivers.dll");
var namespacePrefix = "EquipmentDrivers.";
var fullName = namespacePrefix + equiptmentName;
var type = myAssembly.GetType(fullName);
return (SourceMeter)Activator.CreateInstance(type, primaryGPIBAddress, true);

/*
if (equiptmentName == "Keithley2400")
{
return new Keithley2400(primaryGPIBAddress, true);
}
else if (equiptmentName == "Agilent66XX")
{
return new Agilent66XX(primaryGPIBAddress, true);
}
return null;
*/
}
```

Is this correct?
By the way thanks a million guys, not a single person in the test lab knows how to do this

Comment: And, what happened with that first attempt? AKA, what is your specific problem. SO, is not a place to get people to do all the work for you

Comment: The answer is easy, but the origin of the question confuses me. Why do you need to do this? There are better ways, please motivate why doing it "like this" is the best way?

Comment: If [Jeffery's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20408737/80274) was the correct one, be sure to mark it accepted so he gets credit.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are not part of the .NET type system. They are a convenience offered by most languages. The name that is stored is actually the fully qualified name: namespace and class name.

```
var namespacePrefix = "EquipmentDrivers.";
var fullName = namespacePrefix + equiptmentName;
var type = myAssembly.GetType(fullName);
return Activator.CreateInstance(type, primaryGPIBAddress, true);
```

You could also move the `ReturnSourceMeter` method to the drivers assembly and update it each time a device type is added.

Answer (score 0):

You can look for the type and create an instance from it this way:

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("your.dll");

var type = SampleAssembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Name == "YourTypeName");

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: The context of my question is this. Not all SourceMeters are Keithley SourceMeters, The test routine needs to be generic enough so as to allow the creator of the template file to change the line that says "Keithley2400" to "Agilent66XX"

Comment: The method I have current is conditional and thus if a new piece of equiptment is added the program is not compatiable

Comment: `public SourceMeter ReturnSourceMeter(string equiptmentName, int primaryGPIBAddress)
        {
            if (equiptmentName == "Keithley2400")
            {
                return new Keithley2400(primaryGPIBAddress, true);
            }
            else if (equiptmentName == "Agilent66XX")
            {
                return new Agilent66XX(primaryGPIBAddress, true);
            }
            return null;
        }`

Comment: How do I format that so you guys can see what the hell is going on

Comment: @user2993213 you do it by editing your original question and adding the code there. From what you added, in the above comment it looks like this could be solved by useing a "Dependency Injection" library that uses a configuration file to choose the class type.